# Error in Installing ROracle: LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found

Tags: r, oracle

I am trying to install ROracle for which I have followed the steps as given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36939_01/doc.13/e36763/install_oreclient.htm#OREAD167)

1. Downloading the instant client and sdk from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)
2. Adding the OCI_LIB64 and PATH environment variables as c:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_12_1 where I have kept my client
3. Downloading and installing using install.packages("path to zip", repos = NULL) the client and supporting packages from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/r-enterprise/downloads/index.html)

Now when I try to load the library this happens:

[image]

I have checked my environment variables. They are all okay in the sense they are all pointing to the instant client folder.

### Edit

Adding require("DBI", quietly=TRUE) doesn't help:

[image]

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922243/roracle-dll-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) ?

Comment: Yes. I dont think the loadLibrary failure issue is the same for me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install `DBI` package:

```
  install.packages("DBI")
```

After that, try again with `library("ROracle")`

Comment: Good, adding this code before the open library? require("DBI", quietly=TRUE)

Comment: Tried that. I have aded the screenshot as an edit to my question. Dint work